# Now() in other format

Tags: mysql

I have trigger in my table which adds current date into column upload with type Date but it inserts date as YYYY-MM-DD ( 2015-10-7).I want format to be DD-MM-YYYY and if may 7-OCT-2015.

```
BEGIN
    SET NEW.uploaded = NOW();
END
```

Comment: Use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: in trigger instead of NOW() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%m-%Y')
```

and you can refer to this [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: Doesn't work returns me 0000-00-00.
In column type is Date do I need to change to something else Text, or char?

Comment: Ok I've changed to TEXT type in column and now it works.

Comment: @yaman: `DATE` fields can *only* store dates in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: The best thing is to enter it as a new question, it has many more chances to be evaluated with respect to insert a comment into a question that has already been answered